# Performance issues with loading a lot of data in datagridview

Tags: c#

I created an application that needs a `datagridview` in order to display data, so i created a method that displays the data from MySQL database to the `datagridview` using `datatable`.
 However when i started the application i noticed that the `datagridview` is lagging when i scroll left and right even tho my `datagridview` has around 20-30 record. My question here is how can i possibly enhance its performance since my client will load around 10k of data on it. Several thing i tried was i enabled the double buffer and still i didn't notice any enhancement.

My code so far:

```
void DisplayTable()
    {
        var connection = Connection.prevzemiKonekcija();

        var adapter1 = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        var sqlSelectAll = "SELECT * from prodavnica.artikli";
        adapter1.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlSelectAll, connection);
        var table = new DataTable();
        adapter1.Fill(table);

        var bajndsors = new BindingSource();
        bajndsors.DataSource = table;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bajndsors;


        dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Linen;
        dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Cornsilk;


        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Ред.бр";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Шифра";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Назив";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Набавна цен.";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Продажна цен.";
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Кол.";
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Данок";
        dataGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Опис";
        dataGridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Долг опис";
        dataGridView1.Columns[9].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[10].HeaderText = "Ед.мера";
        dataGridView1.Columns[11].HeaderText = "Профит";
        dataGridView1.Columns[12].HeaderText = "Производител";

        this.dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be seeing any performance problems with only 20 or 30 rows of data, but the way to deal with that in a `DataGridView` is to implement [virtual mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control). You set the `VirtualMode` of the DGV to true, and implement a few event handlers (`CellValueNeeded`, maybe others) to get the data for a particular cell. Your data is stored in some private structure, but is not data bound to the DGV.

Note that enabling virtual mode disables some other features of the DGV. Notably, sorting and autosizing column widths are not available, so if you need those features, you'll need to write your own implementations.

You can use a `DataTable` to store your data, which may be sufficient via the SQL query. I've found that using `DataRow[]` is faster than filling a whole table though.